# Install GUI on server running Ubuntu and remote desktop

Tags: server, gui, remote-desktop

I would like to know how to install a GUI on server machine running Ubuntu and how I can have a remote desktop to it. The important thing is that I would like to be able to use the GUI or my ssh connection to the server.

Comment: Please consider a web interface

Comment: which web interface?